# Perl 5.12 on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: perl

How can I use perl 5.12 on Ubuntu 10.10? There is no distribution package on Ubuntu.

I have to use `feature 'unicode_strings';` in my perl code, and this is available from 5.12. I try to install perl on Ubuntu by `apt-get install perl`, but 5.10 is the latest version.

How can I deal with this? Or is there any code in 5.10 can replace the code `feature 'unicode_strings';`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you should install two version of Perl side by side, because the default 5.10 is a critical part of the system itself, packages are depend on it, a big upgrade to it is not a good idea.

If you want to install Perl 5.16.1 from Larry, you could get the tarball from http://www.perl.org/get.html . Extract it, you could find a file named "INSTALL" which include installation steps. Basically, `sh Configure` `make` `make test` `make install`

If you want ActivePerl 5.14.2 , you could get it from: http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads . Extract it, and `sh install.sh` .

Beware to set the install directory to some place in which you have write permission and not to replace the system's 5.10.